# Laravel policies are resolving weird

Tags: laravel, policy

I need a policy to create trees in a tournament.

So, In my treeController@store, I have:

```
if (Auth::user()->cannot('generateTree', new Tree(),$tournament)) {
        throw new AuthorizationException();
}
```

And my corresponding policy is :

TreePolicy.php:

```
public function generateTree(Tree $tree, Tournament $tournament )
{
    dd($tournament);
    return ($tournament->user_id == Auth::user()->id);
}
```

And I get a :

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Policies\TreePolicy::generateTree() must be an instance of App\Tree, instance of App\User given, called in /laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php on line 382
```

What am I missing???

EDIT : In response to @andonovn,

I tried it with :

```
public function store(User $user, Tree $tree, Tournament $tournament)
{
    dd($tournament);
}
```

And

```
    if (Auth::user()->cannot('generateTree', Tree::class,$tournament)) {
        throw new AuthorizationException();
    }
```

--> it gives me a 403

Or

```
$this->authorize('store',  $tournament,Tree::class);
```

--> it doesn't enter the dd();

The only way I found it to work is putting the Policy content in the controller which is not so nice:

```
if ($tournament->user_id != Auth::user()->id){
        throw new AuthorizationException();
    }
```

EDIT 2 : I solve it with that:

In controller :

```
if (Auth::user()->cannot('store', [Tree::class,$tournament])) {
        throw new AuthorizationException();
    }
```

In policy

```
public function store(User $user, Tournament $tournament)
{
    return ($tournament->user_id == $user->id);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the first argument of generateTree() must be the authenticated user. Try changing it to `public function generateTree(User $user, Tree $tree, Tournament $tournament )`

Edit:
Also change the cannot method to `Auth::user()->cannot('generateTree', [Tree::class, $tournament])` (combine the 2nd and 3rd parameters in array, seems like Laravel is always expecting 2 arguments where the 2nd one can be array)

Comment: it is working well, but then I can't make it work in view, @if (Auth::user()->can('store', [Tree::class, $tournament])) just don't work

Comment: Hmm strange... did you hit the store method on the policy? Try to dump there, maybe the arguments you are passing are somewhat invalid. Also check both your application and server error log for some kind of error. That's just what I would do, I don't see how this would not work when called from the view :/

Comment: no, it is not entering in my policy.... It is just denying the access, even when I am root ( I have a before() method that grant access to root in any case )

Comment: oooo I forgot App\ Before : Tree::class, now working

Comment: :) you may consider using IDE - it will always protect you from such mistakes ;)